# Soft warnings in WebStorm with Dart

Tags: dart, webstorm

I don't get soft warnings correctly displayed in WebStorm with Dart plugin.

See attached screenshots[image]

Warning is displayed on mouse hover, however, the code itself does not get highlighted which makes it hard to spot such a warning.

Is this a bug, or I have just missed some of the WebStorms configuration options?

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug, but a usability issue. Please vote for [WEB-11854](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11854)

Comment: IMHO it is bug, WebStorm has in Editor>Colors & Fonts>General setting for color of *Unused symbol*. It would make a sense to me, if this setting would apply to unused imports.